Problems with react-vertical-timeline-component with next an Type script
1.4 and "typescript": "^5" and i have a problem with a librairie react-vertical-timeline..
My librairie see just a with line without animation and without the card.
And i have see the class the card is defined on : is-hidden.
I know if i put visible=true in  it's ok, so i don't have a animation ans it's not good because i don't use a 100% of my librairie.
I think the problems it's the uncomtability with React librairie and my next application so i don't know..
This is my code :
Experience.tsx :
"use client";

import React from "react";
import {
  VerticalTimeline,
  VerticalTimelineElement,
} from "react-vertical-timeline-component";
import "react-vertical-timeline-component/style.min.css";
import { experiencesData } from "@/constants";

const Experience: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <VerticalTimeline>
      {experiencesData.map((experience, index) => (
        <VerticalTimelineElement
          // visible={true}
          className="vertical-timeline-element--work"
          contentStyle={{ background: "rgb(33, 150, 243)", color: "#fff" }}
          contentArrowStyle={{ borderRight: "7px solid  rgb(33, 150, 243)" }}
          key={index}
          date={experience.date}
          iconStyle={{ background: "rgb(33, 150, 243)", color: "#fff" }}
          icon={<div>{experience.icon}</div>}
        >
          <h3>{experience.title}</h3>
          <h4 className="vertical-timeline-element-subtitle">Miami, FL</h4>
          <p>{experience.description}</p>
        </VerticalTimelineElement>
      ))}
    </VerticalTimeline>
  );
};

export default Experience;

My data for this :
  const arobase = '/docker.webp';

  export const experiencesData = [
    {
      title: "Graduated bootcamp",  
      location: "Miami, FL",
      description:
        "I graduated after 6 months of studying. I immediately found a job as a front-end developer.",
      icon: React.createElement('img', { src: arobase, alt: 'Votre alt' }),
      date: "2019",
    },
    {
      title: "Front-End Developer",
      location: "Orlando, FL",
      description:
        "I worked as a front-end developer for 2 years in 1 job and 1 year in another job. I also upskilled to the full stack.",
        icon: React.createElement('img', { src: arobase, alt: 'Votre alt' }),
      date: "2019 - 2021",
    },
    {
      title: "Full-Stack Developer",
      location: "Houston, TX",
      description:
        "I'm now a full-stack developer working as a freelancer. My stack includes React, Next.js, TypeScript, Tailwind, Prisma and MongoDB. I'm open to full-time opportunities.",
        icon: React.createElement('img', { src: arobase, alt: 'Votre alt' }),
      date: "2021 - present",
    },
  ] as const;

Thanks you for your help !

I know the answer is late, but the problem is that the library uses JavaScript and is broken when brought into Typescript. As far as fixing it, you'd need to go into the library's classes and change them to work with Typescript.

Well, to make this library work with typescript, you need to add the typescript dependency in your project. Just install @types/react-vertical-timeline-component as the devDependencies. Also see, which version is compatible with your existing packages.
My package.json looks something like below:
"dependencies": {
   "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "next": "14.2.5",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.6.0",
 },
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.3.6",
 }

